# Stored Proc: To return rows from Table1 not in Table2 with a condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can someone help me with a Stored Procedure to return the 
NoCond(s) from Table_1 that do not exist in Table_2 for NoPro = AR102

**Table_1**

```
NoCond  Cat
001     G
002     G
003     G
004     G
005     G
006     G
```

**TABLE_2**

```
NoPro   NoCond  Cat
AR101    002    G
AR101    005    G

AR102    003    G
AR102    006    G

AR103    001    G
AR103    005
```

Result should be:

```
NoCond
001
002
004
005
```

Tried examples in replies to question #1598322 and none worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it. It is SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please accept it so other users with same or similar problem know which one was the most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! Edit the comments and run this in your Sql Server Management Studio. It takes a `NoPro` as parameter.
 ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author: Stackoverflow User #325521
-- Create date: 31/01/2014
-- Application: 
-- Description: 
-- Version:     1.0.0.0
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.dcsp_GetNoConds
    @NoProID VARCHAR(16)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT T1.NoCond 
    FROM Table_1 T1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 T2
    ON T1.NoCond = T2.NoCond
    WHERE T2.NoCond IS NULL
        AND T2.NoPro = @NoProID 

END

GO
```

As noted by [@JoePineda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21258/joe-pineda) below in his answer, there are several ways to accomplish the actual record retrieval.

Comment: +1 for the generalization with a param! Problem is, in SQL Server, from time to time I've found it's generally faster to use "NOT EXISTS" or "EXCEPT" than using LEFT JOIN and then compare vs. NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_SP
@NOPRO VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN  
        SELECT T1.NOCOND 
        FROM TABLE_1 T1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 T2
        ON T1.NOCOND = T2.NOCOND
        WHERE T2.NOCOND IS NULL
        AND T2.NOPRO = @NOPRO
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, "NOT EXISTS" is your friend. This code should work in both Oracle and SQL Server - with minimal changes, in mostly every other DBMS:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Table_2 T2
    WHERE T1.NoCond = T2.NoCond
      AND T2.NoPro = 'AR102'
)
```

Should you need *only* the "NoCond" values and know it's to be used on SQL Server, version 2005 or later, then EXCEPT is your friend:

```
SELECT NoCond FROM Table_1 T1
EXCEPT
SELECT NoCond FROM Table_1 T2 WHERE T2.NoPro = 'AR102'
```

For Oracle, substitute "EXCEPT" for "MINUS" and the same applies - it's usually faster.

Comment: Joe, thanks, it works! The problem I have now is that it should return  the columns NoCond and Name from Table_1 and the column Name does not exist in Table_2. I tried adding the column in the select for T1 but because Name is not a column in T2 I get an error.

Comment: Joe, I just tried with NULL as the second parameter in the T1 select and it worked.